# Scanning for Device

Tags: amazon-echo, wifi, google-home, bluetooth

What kind of technology does the Google Home and Amazon Echo/Dot use when you set up the device for the first time and their respective apps "scan for device" before they're connected to Wifi?

I'm trying to implement a similar flow with my device, is it simply bluetooth? What would be the best way to implement this?

Comment: probably UPNP .... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play

Answer (score 6):

Assuming it is Bluetooth (a fair guess as this is the only other radio that is regularly available in mobile phones/tablets), then it will be Bluetooth 4 which will be advertising a BLE Service that has a known set of Characteristics.

- The app running on the phone/tablet will connect to the BLE Service, query a Characteristic for what WiFi SSIDs the device can see.
- It presents this list to the user and ask them to pick one and supply the password required to connect.
- The password and SSID are then sent back to another Characteristic in order to trigger the device to connect to WifI.
- Once connected the Service can then publish it's IP address on yet another Characteristic.

A PoC implementation of all this (and a Web Bluetooth client) can be found on my GitHub page here: https://github.com/hardillb/wifi-provision